# Explain: Big objects don’t support transactions including both big objects, standard object and custom objects

Tags: apex, transaction, big-object

While reading the [Big Object related documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bigobjects.meta/bigobjects/big_object.htm), I was curious as to what does the following statement mean?

> - Big objects don’t support transactions including both big objects, standard object and custom objects.

Consider the following scenario:

1. External system pushing records into BigObjects (Platform/Enterprise WSDL)
2. SOQL to retrieve the records and work off the records to create a custom/standard Sobject record. (Async SOQL not an option because I do not wish to use target sObject to store the retrieved records)
3. Update the BigObject using the "insertImmediate" method with a status as "Processed"

> You can create and update custom big object records in Apex using the insertImmediate method -- **Reference: Documenation - Page 9 Populate Custom BigObject with Apex**

Doesn't the above scenario mean that I would be involved in an Apex transaction with custom Objects as well as the Big Objects?

Answer (score 3):

You are ok to query for Custom/Standard objects but your scenario will not work if you use DML on the Custom/Standard objects followed by an insert on a Big Object unless the Big Object operation is done asynchronously you will get an error. See Database.insertImmediate [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm).
You can insert a Big Object record first and then do DML on a Custom/Standard object but not the opposite direction.

Comment: Will this scenario work? Use SOQL to retrieve records from a Custom Object and use those set of records to insert into BigObjects using insertImmediate method? This is working for me in anonymous Apex, but from this [discussion](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000MVbgQAG), looks like it's throwing error. Thoughts?

Comment: @Sagar are you doing this in a trigger like in that discussion thread? SOQL on a Standard Object is not an issue but DML on a Standard Object is, so you'd need to call the big object update asynchronously.

Comment: do you know why I can't do a DML on the Standard/Custom object followed by a DML on the BigObjects and followed by a DML on the Standard/Custom object? I am trying to wrap my head around the fact that DML on BigObjects are actually Callouts? I found out the reason why? **Update:** [https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_testing_dml.htm]

Comment: @Sagar the link isn't working for me but take a look at the insertImmediate method here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm You can either insert the Big Object first and then the SObject or do the insert on the Big Object asynchronously.

Comment: @JennyB Does that mean if you retrieved Big Object using SOQL it won't amount to heap size?